# Compute $\det(A + tI)$ (Exercise 4.3.24 in Linear algebra by Friedberg)

Tags: linear-algebra

This is Exercise 4.3.24 in Linear algebra by Friedberg.

> Let $A \in M_{n \times n} $ have the form 
>   $\begin{pmatrix} 
> 0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 & a_0\\ -1 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 &a_1 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 & ... &0 & a_2 \\\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &...&\vdots&\vdots \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & . . . & -1 & a_{n-1}
> \end{pmatrix}$
>
> Copmpute $\det(A + tI)$, where $I$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix.

I was thinking about expressing $A$ into the product of two matrices and using the property that $\det(A)$ is the product of the determinant of each matrix. But, I am stuck here, and I am not sure if this is the right way to solve this question. I appreciate if you give any help.

Comment: Don't go into this complicated way (product of matrices). You are (up to minus signs) asked to compute the characteristic polynomial of what is known as a "companion matrix".

Comment: Perhaps you can induct on $n$ and use cofactor expansion to compute the determinant.

Comment: See https://math.solverer.com/library/stephen_friedberg/linear_algebra/exercise_4-3-24?utm_source=stackexchange.com&utm_medium=link